# Merge 2 XML Files Into Same Elements C#

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, http, soa

I need to create a WebService that takes the name of a city as input and returns Location, Country and Weather information of the City. The thing is that the ID, Location, Country is in one XML file and all weather details in another.

```XML
<City>
<ID>city1</ID>
<Grid_ref>NG 895608</Grid_ref>
<Name>Berlin</Name>
<Country>Germany</Country>
</City>
```

```XML
<cityWeather>
<ID>city1</ID>
<temperature>20</temperature>
<wind>2</wind>
</cityWeather>
```

Using c# is it possible to merge everything into 1 file using ID or is there some other way I can do it? I would then search the XML file once, as having 2 different files mixes me up.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The "best" way depends on what other XML processing you are doing (.NET has multiple XML parser APIs and then there is XSLT…)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataSet. I suppose you have two XML files. CityWeather.xml et City.xml, you can make this

```
try
    {
        XmlTextReader xmlreader1 = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Books1.xml");
        XmlTextReader xmlreader2 = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Books2.xml");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader1);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        ds2.ReadXml(xmlreader2);
        ds.Merge(ds2);
        ds.WriteXml("C:\\Books.xml");
        Console.WriteLine("Completed merging XML documents");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
Console.Read();
```

You can make any changes that meet your need

hope it helps

Comment: Yes that is right thanks. So the above will place them in the same <city> tag according to their ID?

Comment: does books.xml have to be empty?  I've replaced books1/books2 with City.Xml and CityWeather.Xml adding them to a blank CityMerged.Xml..however the city merge remains blank?

Comment: I put this in CityServices.cs, program.cs runs the server without errors. However it remains blank and not including all the details in one.

Answer (score 1):

Use add

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cityXML =
            "<Root>" +
                "<City>" +
                    "<ID>city1</ID>" +
                    "<Grid_ref>NG 895608</Grid_ref>" +
                    "<Name>Berlin</Name>" +
                    "<Country>Germany</Country>" +
                "</City>" +
                "<City>" +
                    "<ID>city2</ID>" +
                    "<Grid_ref>F 5608</Grid_ref>" +
                    "<Name>Paris</Name>" +
                    "<Country>France</Country>" +
                "</City>" +
                "<City>" +
                    "<ID>city3</ID>" +
                    "<Grid_ref>RR 608</Grid_ref>" +
                    "<Name>Rome</Name>" +
                    "<Country>Italy</Country>" +
                "</City>" +
             "</Root>";


            XElement cities = XElement.Parse(cityXML);

            string weatherXML =
            "<Root>" +
                "<cityWeather>" +
                    "<ID>city1</ID>" +
                    "<temperature>20</temperature>" +
                    "<wind>2</wind>" +
                "</cityWeather>" +
                "<cityWeather>" +
                    "<ID>city2</ID>" +
                    "<temperature>30</temperature>" +
                    "<wind>3</wind>" +
                "</cityWeather>" +
                "<cityWeather>" +
                    "<ID>city3</ID>" +
                    "<temperature>40</temperature>" +
                    "<wind>4</wind>" +
                "</cityWeather>" +
            "</Root>";

            XElement weather = XElement.Parse(weatherXML);

            List<XElement> cityList = cities.Descendants("City").ToList(); 
            foreach(XElement city in cityList)
            {
                XElement matchedCity = weather.Descendants("cityWeather").Where(x =>
                    x.Element("ID").Value == city.Element("ID").Value).FirstOrDefault();
                if(matchedCity != null) city.Add(matchedCity);
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Will I have to do this for all the cities however? There are quite a few

Comment: It is easy to do with multiple cities with XL Linq.  Need to see a example with multiple cities where the city name is the same in both XML.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with link and wont manage on my own. I thought the above example of Fatiha was good, though it doesnt really seem to work

Comment: The xml file contains around 50 other cities, all with their own weather city1,city2, city3 - I want to merge as I when I search for Paris I want to return all the detils for Paris - found in city.xml and cityweather.xml

<City>
<ID>city1</ID>
<Grid_ref>NG 895608</Grid_ref>
<Name>Berlin</Name>
<Country>Germany</Country>
</City>
<City>
<ID>city2</ID>
<Grid_ref>F 5608</Grid_ref>
<Name>Paris</Name>
<Country>France</Country>
</City>
<City>
<ID>city3</ID>
<Grid_ref>RR 608</Grid_ref>
<Name>Rome</Name>
<Country>Italy</Country>
</City>

Comment: I updates the code to show an example of how to merge the two xml.  You didn't post a multiple weather xml so I created one that contains city names.  The XML cities contains the merged file.